# Material design Sliders

Tags: android, slider, material-design

In the android developers site they tell about Sliders:
[Sliders](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/sliders.html#)

Yet i cant find any where which exaplain how to add them to the project and use them

Can someone point me to such resource?

Answer (score 1):

I think the AppCompatSeekBar (See the support library) is what you're searching for.